# Can't get algorithm to work

Tags: php, algorithm, object, foreach

I am working on an algorithm and having an array of objects, I need to print the first attribute of each object, than the second attribute and so on. I do not know the names or the number of attributes the object has.
Currently, my algorithm gets each object and prints all the attributes, using a `foreach` statement.

Could anyone please suggest a solution?

```
foreach ($variants as $variant) {
  $combination = $this->Product_model->getVariationCombination($variant->id);

  if ($combination!=NULL)
    foreach($combination as $combi){
      echo $variant_options[$combi->product_variant_option_value_id];
    }
}
```

This is kind of a lot of different things, but I'll try to explain it.
`$variant_options` holds all the possible values for a product's attribute. (color -> red, for example).
`$combination` has all the different attributes of a product (say all the types of t-shirts available).
Now, what I would have to do is print the first`$variant_options[$combi->product_variant_option_value_id]`, then for the second and so on, instead of printing everything for each $combination at a time.
So, instead of printing all colors and then all sizes or whatever attributes are there, it should print the color of a t-shirt, then the size and so on.

If needed, I can provide the contents of any of the variables

Answer (score 0):

You can use get_object_vars to get all an object's public attributes into an associative array, than you go operate on that array however you want to display or access the attributes. If the attributes are protected/private, you'll need a method to return the attributes.

```
foreach($variants as $variant){
    $properties = get_object_vars($variant);
    var_dump($properties);
    }
}


class TShirt {
    
    public $color;
    public $size;

    public function __construct($color, $size){
        $this->size = $size;
        $this->color = $color;
    }
}

$a = new TShirt('red', 'medium');
$b = new TShirt('blue', 'large');

$shirts = array($a, $b);

foreach($shirts as $shirt){
    
    $properties = get_object_vars($shirt);
    foreach ($properties as $key=>$value){
        echo "The {$key} is {$value}.";
    }
}
```

Documentation: https://www.php.net/get_object_vars